# How to insert data in to memcacheq in batch mode by using shell?

Tags: shell, batch-file, insert

I want to insert lots of data into memecacheq by using shell script, it seems commands like below doesn't work:

insert data "123" with queue name "test_key"

```
echo -e 'set test_key 0 0 3\n123' | nc localhost 22201
```

memcacheq is running on local host and listening port 22201.

However, if I do like below, it will work:

```
telnet localhost 22201
```

And then

```
set test_key 0 0 3
123
```

Comment: RESOLVED by issue below command: echo -ne 'set test_key 0 0 3\r\n123\r\n' | nc localhost 22201

Comment: you can post your own answer, and then accept it (after 2 days) to gain rep points. Good show. Interesting problem.